# Google blocks smtp in react-native

Tags: react-native, smtp-auth

I am having trouble with google smtp for sending emails from my app.

The app works fine in my mobile and I am able to send emails without any issue.

But When I publish the app and people start using it, I get a security email from google telling me that it has blocked a login try.

I have even enabled less secure login.

Is there any other settings I should enable?

### Here is my code for sending emails

```js
import RNSmtpMailer from 'react-native-smtp-mailer'

async sendEmail(email: string, htmlBody: string, subject: string) {
  try {
    var settings = await this.getAppSettings();
    if (!settings)
      throw "Could not find the smtp settings"
    var success = await RNSmtpMailer.sendMail({
      mailhost: settings.smtp,
      port: settings.port,
      ssl: true, // optional. if false, then TLS is enabled. Its true by default in android. In iOS TLS/SSL is determined automatically, and this field doesn't affect anything
      username: settings.email,
      password: settings.password,
      fromName: "NovelManager", // optional
      replyTo: undefined, // optional
      recipients: email,
      bcc: [], // optional
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: htmlBody,
      attachmentPaths: [], // optional
      attachmentNames: [], // required in android, these are renames of original files. in ios filenames will be same as specified in path. In a ios-only application, no need to define it
    });
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

### and here is the smtp settings

```
{
  smtp: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: "465",
  email: "test@gmail.com", // not the real email
  password: "test"
}
```

Comment: Every strings, including password, secrets etc is visible to the client, this includes your email and password. You should never put secrets in your mobile app, rather use a back-end server that sends email without giving away your password to the client.  https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/

Comment: This is not the issue my friend. All the code are opfoctated so there is no issue of finding out the setting. And the setting are stored in firebase and not in the app. Now my issue is the smtp for google blocking the login attempt when other people using the app.

Comment: Sending emails through SMTP in an app is a terrible design choice. If SMTP were open, phones would be used to launch spam all the time. Look for an alternate solution. Mails should not be sent from the device directly (unless it’s using the appropriate email client and with explicit approval/action by the user).

Comment: I am using it to send email when a user forget password or create a new account. I do not own a server and that is why I am doing it like this. This should not be a problem as I enabled less secure login in google but for some reason I am still getting the problem.

Comment: Your best option would be to create a Firebase Cloud Function and write your SMTP code over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok at last I found a solution, And that is using app password instead of simple password.

I am posting the solution here incase anyone is intressted.